# Copy formula in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In a sheet, I refer to a formula on another sheet (in cell K2). However, if an entire line is deleted in the first sheet, the formula on the second sheet gives #REF!.

I therefore typed the text of the formula (without the "="-sign) in another cell (in cell K4). I would like to restore the formula in K2 by copying the text in K4 and pasting it in K2.

This code returns

> Runtime error 1004: application-defined or object-defined error

on the line `Sheets("StdLine").Range("K2").Formula = stdformula`

The formula is:

```
CONCATENATE(RAL!B2;IF(RAL!C2="";"";"|"&RAL!C2);": P"&MONTH(RAL!A2)&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(RAL!A2);2);"-R"&MONTH(RAL!I2)&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(RAL!I2);2);":";IF(RAL!D2="";"";" "&RAL!D2);IF(RAL!E2="";"";" ("&RAL!E2&")");": F"&ROUND(RAL!G2;2)&RAL!F2;" > iP"&IF(RAL!F2="d";ROUND(RAL!G2/7,2*8;2)&"d = "&ROUND(RAL!G2*8;2)&"h";ROUND(RAL!G2;2)&"h");TEXT(I2;" (dd/mm/jjjj uu:mm:ss)"))
```

Here is a part of my code:

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Target.EntireRow.Address Then
        stdformula = "=" & Sheets("StdLine").Range("K4")
        Sheets("StdLine").Range("K2").Formula = stdformula
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `.Formula` (which only excepts standard english formulas with comma as separator) you need to use `.FormulaLocal` for localized formulas (other languages or other separators).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.Formula` (which only excepts standard english formulas with comma as separator) you need to use `.FormulaLocal` for localized formulas (other languages or other separators).